# Codeigniter : how to update mulitiple record where id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have been looking for ways but find suitable speckle. so, i have **table product** and **I show along with his ID**. and I put in a form. and **when I press the update button then what had been updated in the form of their corresponding id**.

my view :

```
<?php echo form_open('stock/updating_stock');?>
  <div class="panel-body scroll-menu" style="margin-top:0px;height:170px;padding-top:5px;">
    <?php foreach($critical_plus_warning as $data){?>
      <input type="hidden" name="id_product[]" value="<?php echo $data->id_product;?>">
      <h5 class="hidden-xs"><b><?php echo $data->product_name;?></b> <input type="text" class="pull-right" style="width:10%;margin-left:10px;text-align:center;" name="update_stock[]" value="<?php echo $data->stock?>">
      <?php 
      $stock = $data->stocks;
      if($stock < 10){
        echo "<label style='font-size:13px;' class='label label-danger pull-right'>$stock</label>";
      }else{
        echo "<label style='font-size:13px;' class='label label-warning pull-right'>$stock</label>";
      }
      ?>
      </h5>
      <h5 class="hidden-lg"><b><?php $limited_word = word_limiter($data->product_name,3); echo $limited_word; ?></b> <input class="pull-right" type="text" style="width:10%;margin-left:10px;text-align:center;" name="update_stock[]" value="<?php echo $data->stocks?>"> 
      <?php 
      $stock = $data->stocks;
      if($stock < 10){
        echo "<label style='font-size:13px;' class='label label-danger pull-right'>$stock</label>";
      }else{
        echo "<label style='font-size:13px;' class='label label-warning pull-right'>$stock</label>";
      }
      ?>
      </h5>
    <?php }?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-5px;background-color:white;padding:6px;background-color:white;box-shadow:0px 0px 8px 0px #bababa;"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save data</button></div>
  <?php echo form_close();?>
```

and my controller :

```
function updating_stock(){

    $id = $this->input->post('id_product');
    $stok = $this->input->post('update_stock');
    $user = $this->data['id'];

    for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
    $data = array(
       array(
        'id'        => $id,
        'stok'      => $stok,
        'diubah'    => $user,
        'tgl_diubah'=> date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
        ),
    );
    }
    //print_r($data);
    $this->stok_adm->update_stok($data);
}
```

and my models :

```
function update_stok($data){
    $this->db->update_batch($this->table, $data,'id_product');
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a where clause:

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
```

...I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Controller

```
function updating_stock(){

$id = $this->input->post('id_product');
$stok = $this->input->post('update_stock');
$user = $this->data['id'];

for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
$data = array(
   array(
    'id'        => $id,
    'stok'      => $stok,
    'diubah'    => $user,
    'tgl_diubah'=> date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
    ),
);
}
//print_r($data);
$this->stok_adm->update_stok($data,$id);
```

}

Model:

```
function update_stok($data,$id){
$this->db->update_batch($this->table, $data,'id_product');
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think in your example *update_batch* will generate incorrect query beacues you need to update each record in db instead of updating them together - *update_batch* replaces values in multiple rows which fulfills conditions so there is possibility to update also incorrect rows (check example in [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch#selecting-data)). So better idea is to update each single product using it's ID. It could look like that:

Model

```
function update_stok($data, $id_product){
    $this->db->where('id_product', $id_product);
    return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
}
```

Controller

```
function updating_stock(){
    $ids = $this->input->post('id_product');
    $stok = $this->input->post('update_stock');
    $user = $this->data['id'];

    foreach($ids as $key => $id_product) {
        $data = array(
            'stok'      => $stok[$key],
            'diubah'    => $user,
            'tgl_diubah'=> date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
        );
        $this->stok_adm->update_stok($data, $id_product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title');
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=update_batch

Comment: so your code should be:

for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){
    $data = array(
       array(
        'id_product'        => $id,
        'stok'      => $stok,
        'diubah'    => $user,
        'tgl_diubah'=> date('Y:m:d H:i:s'),
        ),
    );
    }
    //print_r($data);
    $this->stok_adm->update_stok($data);